# Select a row where certain columns never failed certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following rows that is returned from a query:

```
name  number
foo     1
foo     9
foo     10
foo     11
bar     12
bar     13
dumb    14
```

How do I select the name where the number of such name is never under 10, and appear at least twice so this case, i wanted it to return

```
name
bar
```

What I have tried:

```
select name from my_table
where number >= 10 #<--Problem
group by name
having count(*) >=2
```

This works partially because it was not able to filter out foo. The problem of this query is that it will be able to filter out `foo 1` and `foo 9` but `foo 10` and `foo 11` will be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name from my_table 
group by name 
having count(*) >=2 and min(number) >= 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that makes me feel like this is a stupid question. Sorry, I just started to learn database and created many  dummy tables to play around.

Comment: what if the second column is a string and I wanted to select the name that has a second column that never have value that start with certain string?

Comment: @aDev you are then going to need to do a not exists query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996352/select-a-row-where-column-value-start-with-string-and-does-not-start-with-string this is the new question with what I described, take a look if you are interested.