# Select a row where column value start with string and does not start with string

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following rows

```
name    StringValue
foo     Mac123

foo     Windows123

foo     Andorid123

bar     Windows123

bar     Andorid123

dumb    Windows123
```

This is the result tuples returned from query below:

```
select name, stringValue from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE13 C
where A.id = B.id
and B.id = C.id
GROUP BY name, stringValue
```

How do I select the name where the stringValue of such name never contained a string that start with "Mac", but also needs to contains the value that start with "Windows"

this should return

```
name
bar
dumb
```

What I have:

```
select name, stringValue from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE13 C
where A.id = B.id
and B.id = C.id
GROUP BY name, stringValue
Having stringValue LIKE "Windows" and stringValue not LIKE "Mac"
```

Problem: Above query returns all columns that start with the name "Windows". Since if the first half condition is true, the second half is true as well.

I think the problem has to do with my having by not working as I wanted it too..

How do I modify the query so it returns all the names where any column with this name, will have a string value that does not start with Mac, but also start with Windows.

Comment: Join the table to itself with a group by on name, and matches the "Mac%" like, then only include rows that don't match the joined table. Also, use the modern form JOIN syntax when referencing multiple tables in a SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of joins for this. Aggregation with a specific `HAVING` clause should do it:

```
SELECT name
FROM t
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN stringvalue LIKE 'WINDOWS%' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN stringvalue LIKE 'MAC%'     THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=62a9c35a315e21fad1e432d25d43e12e)

Answer (score 2):

Use a having clause and check for the sums of the strings' beginnings. This works because in MySQL Boolean expressions evaluate to `0` when false and `1` when true.

```
SELECT name
       FROM a
            INNER JOIN b
                       ON b.id = a.id
            INNER JOIN c
                       ON c.id = b.id
       GROUP BY name
       HAVING sum(stringvalue LIKE 'Mac%') = 0
              AND sum(stringvalue LIKE 'Windows%') > 0;
```

Comment: just for information. Why don't we filter those strings in the `where` clause?

Comment: Because we don't want to limit the individual row but all the rows in a group.

Comment: I don't get yet why the output changes (in this particular case)

Comment: In addition... I am not an expert in mysql, but is it possible to `sum` the `stringvalue` field, which is supposed a `varchar` one?

Comment: It isn't `stringvalue` that is summed, it are the `LIKE` operations. `stringvalue` is an operand in them.

Comment: Ah ok, so that means if the condition is true then `sum` 1?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: ok thank you :D. I am still wondering why the outputs could be different filtering the data in the `where`

Comment: @JaimeDrq since OP is interested in checking no macs and at least one windows a where clause `WHERE stringvalue like 'mac%' or stringvalue like 'windows%'` could be added. But `HAVING` is required to ensure that after filtering we have at least one windows and zero macs in the filtered results. Having is evaluated after where. HTH.